# Dynamically pass arguments to objects.filter

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views

I am pretty new to Django and I am trying to get a query set from a filter function. This filter function is supposed to be able to take 1 to 5 arguments and I am not sure how to handle that.

I have not found anything here that might help me, so if you do know of some other question that might help please let me know.

`views.py`:

```
@api_view(('Get',))

def update(request, REQUEST):

    if request.method == "Get":
        requestlist = REQUEST.split('&')
        for keys in requestlist:
            if 'module' in keys:
                module = keys[8:]
            if 'value' in keys:
                value = keys[6:]
            if 'user' in keys:
                user= keys[5:]
            if 'time1' in keys:
                time1 = keys[6:]
            if 'time2' in keys:
                time2 = keys[6:]
        item = Post.objects.filter(name=Name, user=USER, ...)
```

The full request string will look like `name=NAME&value=VALUE&user=USER&time1=FIRSTTIME&time2=SECONDTIME` but it could also be any combination of the individual variables like `name&time1`.

Now I want to be able to do that with one filter method instead of creating like 2^5 for each different szenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The full request string will look like `name=NAME&value=VALUE&user=USER&time1=FIRSTTIME&time2=SECONDTIME`.

This is a [*query string* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string), and Django automatically parses this to a dictionary-like `QueryDict`, you thus should *not* specify this yourself. You can work with:

```
if request.method == 'GET':
    Post.objects.filter(**request.GET.dict())
```

I would however advise to only allow specific keys, and thus not all keys, since then the database is less secure: one can use the filtering mechanism to retrieve data.

It thus might be better to work with:

```
datas = {}
accept_keys = {'module', 'value', 'user', 'time1', 'time2'}

for key, value in request.GET.dict().items():
    if key in accept_keys:
        datas[key] = value

if request.method == 'GET':
    Post.objects.filter(**datas)
```

In that case the item *after* the path is the query string, and the separator between the path and the query string is a question mark (`?`).

The path thus looks like:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # …,
    path('some/path/', views.update, name='update'),
    # …
]
```

and you thus query the path with `some.host.com/some/path?name=NAME&value=VALUE&user=USER&time1=FIRSTTIME&time2=SECONDTIME`.